# How to select a column in SQL relative to another one

Tags: mysql

I have this data base structure:

[image: structure]

The field `id` is the primary key. I am trying to find all courses that have `department='civil' & level=4`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE department = 'civil' AND level = 4`

Comment: You should review a good SQL tutorial to learn the basics.  This isn't a great way to learn about SQL.

Comment: ok, thanks alot.Thats working good

Comment: I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kousik mandal 's answer is correct. But let me give a short explaination to how it works. (since you obviously didn't look online first)

```
SELECT course_name       -- This is the column that you will recieve. if you pick * instead of course_name it will select all columns which match the criteria.
FROM table_name          -- you select the course_name from the table 'table_name'
WHERE department='civil' -- This will select columns where the department column has 'civil' as a value
AND level=4              -- This will also check if the level equals to 4.
```

This might not be as helpful since the answer is already given. but I hope it'll give you some useful information for learning SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select course_name from table_name where department='civil' and level=4
```